# Sort program not working, not sure why

Tags: c, cs50

```c
void sort(int values[], int n)
{
    int smallestSpot = 0;
    for (long long i = 0; i < n ; i++)
    {
        int smallest = values[i];
        for(long long j = i; j < n - i ; j++) //find the smallest int in array
        {
            if(values[j] < smallest)
            {
                smallestSpot = j;
                smallest = values[j];
            }
        }
        values[smallestSpot] = values[i];
        values[i] = smallest;
    }
    return;
}
```

My sorting algorithm overwrites what the first number is, and I can't find out why, please help. Thanks.

Comment: Have you stepped through it with a debugger, or inspected the variables by printing them out?

Comment: `long long j = i;` --> `long long j = i + 1;`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ thats how I had it originally and it didn't work

Comment: Also `j < n - i ` --> `j < n`

Comment: @Carcigenicate yeah, I printed like every output and used the debugger, I just can't figure it out. I've been staring at this code for like 20 minutes and it wasn't coming to me. I was hoping a fresh pair of eyes would help.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ did both of those thing sand it still doesn't work.

Comment: add this line `smallestSpot = i` before entering the second loop. Consider the situation that element at index `0` is smallest, and that at index `1` is next smallest then in that case the when `i=1` and just after completing inner `for` loop, your element at index `0` will be overwritten by the element at index `1`. because `samllestSpot` is `0`. Moreover, not need to use `long long int` for  indexing an array and number of elements in the array `n` is itself `int`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for COLDSPEED and GAURANG VYAS by perform that changes we reachs to working version of code.

## Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
 
void sort(int values[], int n){
 
    int smallestSpot = 0;
 
    for (long long i = 0; i < n ; i++){
 
        int smallest = values[i];
        smallestSpot = i;
 
        for(long long j = i+1; j < n  ; j++){ //find the smallest      int in array
            if(values[j] < smallest){
                smallestSpot = j;
                smallest = values[j];
            }
        }
 
            values[smallestSpot] = values[i];
            values[i] = smallest;   
    }
}
 
 
int main(void){
 
    int arr[5] = {8,1,9,10,2};
    sort(arr,5);
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        printf("%d\n",arr[i]);
    }
 
    return 0;   
}
```

Before try to coding trace your algorithm with pen and paper.
We have many sorting algorithms i suggest to see [this](https://brilliant.org/wiki/sorting-algorithms/) link and gain a visual understanding about sorting problems and way of solving them.

**Edit**

- [Show output](https://ideone.com/O8Ri4R)

Comment: Would be nice to provide a working sample with ideone... but +1 nonetheless.

Comment: @cs95 I really recommend trying repl.it it's worth it, it provides a shell as well if you need to include a library like ncurses